# Erasing everything that is not selected?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-cs4

I'm using Photoshop CS4. Is there is a way to erase/delete everything that is not selected? Instead of the usual scenario of erasing everything that is selected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inverse selection.

On Windows: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>. Or `Select` menu, then `Inverse`.

Comment: On Windows, Ctrl+Shift+I or go to the Select menu -> Inverse

Comment: can we delete only outside of selection and keeping inside? also asking @studiohack

Comment: @MonsterMMORPG Not entire sure what you mean... If you mean 'Select All', I believe thats CTRL+A?